# Why do I just get "?? " when I try to get the reference of a equation with \autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I use `\autoref` to reference everything in my Thesis. I get without problem the references of the images and the Tables but when I try to get the references of a equation I get just `??`.

```
\noindent
Die Standardform eines Optimierungsproblems ist in \autoref{eq:generalOptimization} dargestellt.\\

\begin{align}
f(x)&   \longrightarrow  min/max  & x& =(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n ) \nonumber  \\
wobei,          \qquad   g_i(x)& \leq 0                      & i& =(1,\dots,m) \label{eq:generalOptimization}\\
                         h_j(x)& = 0                         & j& = (1,\dotsb,p) \nonumber  
\end{align}\\
```

[image: here can you see what i get]

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?? maybe is a problem with the packages that i am im using:

```
\usepackage[left=3.2cm, right=2cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=2.19cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,font={sf,footnotesize},format=plain}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} 
\usepackage{siunitx }
\usepackage{units} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplots}




\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!10]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text badly centered, text width=3cm,  draw=black, , fill=green!10]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text badly centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, text badly centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, fill=green!30, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{invisible}=[coordinate]

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.jpg,.png}


\usepackage{setspace} 
 \usepackage{cleveref}

 %============================================


 \makeatletter
 \def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
 \hbox{}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \newpage
 \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
 \makeatother

 %==========================================


\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\lstset{frame=tb,   
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray},  
  frame=single,   
  language=c,
  aboveskip=5mm,
  belowskip=5mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}, 
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true
  tabsize=3
}

%% PDF metadata
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle = {b},
    pdfsubject = {Ermittlung hochaufloesender Motor-Lastkollektive in unterschiedlichen Kundennutzungsprofilen},
    pdfkeywords = { automotive, testing, belastungskollektive,kundennuntzungsprofil},
    pdfauthor = {Juan Mauricio Toro Ramos },
    pdfcreator = \LaTeX,
    pdfproducer= {a},

}
}{}

\makeatother
\hypersetup{ 
    colorlinks=true,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    citecolor=blue,%
    unicode%
}

%===================================

\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

%=======================
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you using `\usepackage{mathtools}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}`? This should provide the correct reference

Comment: not an answer about `\autoref`, but a comment on the form of the input: this could (better, i think) be coded as `\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \end{equation}`.  that would yield only a single equation number, in the same location; no `\nonumber`.  also, get rid of the blank line before the display -- the spacing will be better (lots of reference to this in other questions); enter `\text{wobei}` so it won't be treated as five separate variables multiplied together; and use `\min` and `\max` for the same reason.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer unfortunately i get  still the problem when i compile my document. I've Updated the question with the Packages that im using

Comment: @JuanMauricioToro: I am busy right now, I will look later on

Comment: The package `cleveref` should be loaded *after* `hyperref`. Both packages should generally be loaded last, i.e., after all other packages have been loaded.

Comment: @JuanMauricioToro: See the comment by Mico or my updated answer

Comment: See [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](http://goo.gl/W5GtJ2)

Comment: Problem solved!! certainly the problem was the position of the cleveref... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `\usepackage{mathtools}` for `\begin{align}...\end{align}` as well for `\text{}` (improving non-math-typesetting within formulas).

The main issue however is `\usepackage{hyperref}` for `\autoref` to work. Compile twice, to see the effect.

**Edit:** My first version of this solution was posted before the OP added his 'MWE', but now it's quite clear, that the wrong position of including `cleveref` package is the cause of the problem (Mico commented already on this)

`cleveref` is one of rare cases where a package must be included **after** `\usepackage{hyperref}` in order to make cross-references correct.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Die Standardform eines Optimierungsproblems ist in \autoref{eq:generalOptimization} dargestellt.

\begin{align}
f(x)&   \longrightarrow  min/max  & x& =(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n ) \nonumber  \\
\text{wobei}          \qquad   g_i(x)& \leq 0                      & i& =(1,\dots,m) \label{eq:generalOptimization}\\
h_j(x)& = 0                         & j& = (1,\dotsb,p) \nonumber  
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]